# Submitting symfony register controller fosuserbundle does not work

Tags: symfony, controller, fosuserbundle

I tried to follow this tutorial to override default controller of fos user bundle  [Overriding Default FOSUserBundle Controllers][1]

And i can change controller but when  I try to submit button it doesn't work:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Controller/RegistrationController.php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController as BaseController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class RegistrationController extends BaseController
{
    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
        /** @var $formFactory FactoryInterface */
        $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');
        /** @var $userManager UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        /** @var $dispatcher EventDispatcherInterface */
        $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');

        $user = $userManager->createUser();
        $user->setEnabled(true);

        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);
 var_dump('prova');

        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
            return $event->getResponse();
        }

    $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationType::class, $user, [
    'method' => 'POST',
]);

    //$form = $formFactory->createForm();
    //$form->setData($user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        var_dump($form);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
           var_dump($form);
              }
        }

        return $this->render('@FOSUser/Registration/register.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

The var_dump before the submit work but the var_dump inside

```
if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            if ($form->isValid()) {
```

doesn't work . I believe that submit logic is in another code but i don't understand how I can change it.

I  don't understand how it's possible. Please help  me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't set a formType to your form, so he have nothing to handle.

Here is a simple example :

```
$form = $this->createForm(YourFormType::class, $user, [
        'method' => 'POST',
]);
```

Good luck ! :)

Comment: thank's for answer ......     i change the code with this but still don't work...       $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationType::class, $user, [
        'method' => 'POST',
]);
        
        //$form = $formFactory->createForm();
        //$form->setData($user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
 
        if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            var_dump($form);
            if ($form->isValid()) {
               var_dump($form);

Comment: ok, can you check the request method pls ? var_dump($request->getMethod());

Comment: you are right ! i don't know why but is 'GET' method

Comment: Ah ah ! Ok it must be your view, check if your form "action" correctly send a POST.

Comment: uhm....   {{ form_start(form, {'method': 'post', 'action': path('fos_user_registration_register'), 'attr': {'class': 'fos_user_registration_register'}}) }}

Comment: ok i understand that there is something wrong in views because in default template var_dump sumbit work ... Thank' s to help me